# how to make the applications developed by pyqt5 support Chinese input on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5

On ubuntu, I developed an application using pyqt5, but it does not support Chinese input(My sogouPinyin input method cannot show Chinese context menu when I want to type text on my application). My OS supports Chinese input. How to fix it?

Comment: Thank you for your advice., but how to solve this problem?

Comment: Actually I have no idea, I'm investigating but it seems that Qt does not support it by default, I'm seeing if there is a plugin to enable that functionality.

Comment: Do other applications of your OS use sogouPinyin ?, if so, could you tell me some of those applications.

Comment: Yes, such google chrome, vscode. sublime txt needs a fix package to support Chinese input.

Comment: try installing: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/fcitx-qt5

Comment: It still does not work. but thank you very much!!! This problem seems like sublime text ones, It is fixed by this https://github.com/lyfeyaj/sublime-text-imfix. Can this information help?

Comment: what is the output of  `import os; print(os.environ['QT_IM_MODULE'])`?

Answer (score 2):

1. install some packages.

```sh
    sudo apt install fcitx-frontend-qt5 fcitx-libs-qt fcitx-libs-qt5
```

2. copy lib to pyqt folder.

```sh
    sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin.so ${PYTHON_HOME}/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts/
```

3. add `os.environ['QT_IM_MODULE'] = 'fcitx'` in main file. (maybe not necessary.)

[reference](https://blog.csdn.net/ouening/article/details/79588959)

Answer (score 1):

sogouPinyin is based on Fcitx, so for the case of Qt applications the [docs](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables) indicates that you have to use the flag `QT_IM_MODULE`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import os
    os.environ['QT_IM_MODULE'] = 'fcitx'
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit())
    lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTextEdit())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After the application is open you must place the focus in an editing widget such as QLineEdit, QTextEdit and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to enable it.

But you have to have installed [fcitx-qt5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/fcitx-qt5) package:

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install fcitx-qt5 fcitx fcitx-frontend-qt5
```

Comment: I install these packages using apt  successfully except fcitx-qt5, so i build package from source and make install successfully. Next i add a line code `os.environ['QT_IM_MODULE'] = 'fcitx'`  in my main file. But it cannot work. Do i loss some steps?

Comment: apt Unable to locate package fcitx-qt5. I do it according to your instructions, but the input context menu can not show.

Comment: I installed libfcitx-qt5-dev and reboot my PC. it cannot work.

Comment: @Daibingh Does Sogoupinyin work in other applications?

Comment: I wonder the line code `os.environ['QT_IM_MODULE'] = 'fcitx'` 's function, can it make the pyqt5 find the fcitx-qt5 package?  Qt creator cannot support chinese input initally, but it can  after copy `libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin.so` generated by building fcitx-qt5 to Qt creator installed folder. Should I do something like this?

Comment: I solve the problem. I need copy `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin.so` to `${PYTHON_HOME}/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts/`. After this step, the Chinese input context menu can show normally.

Comment: Thanks you very much.!!! I am very grateful for your patience and help.

Comment: @Daibingh mmm, interesting, in my case my PyQt5 directly uses the Qt5 plugins so I did not have to do it.